# XQuery - Optimize a query for a BIG database

Tags: oracle11g, query-optimization, xquery, marklogic

I have a big xml database (30 000 files, 1.3 Go). One file in this database lists all the other files present in the database. My aim is "simply" to check if all files listed are present in the database. BUT I must not take care of the name of the files but only the XML code inside the documents.

This is something like that :

```
declare variable $root :=  fn:collection();

declare function local:isValid($fileCode) {

let $fileSearchedIdentCode := $root/dmodule/identity/dmCode
return 
$fileCode/@attribute1 = $fileSearchedIdentCode/@attribute1 and
$fileCode/@attribute2 = $fileSearchedIdentCode/@attribute2 and
$fileCode/@attribute3 = $fileSearchedIdentCode/@attribute3

};

<result>
{ 
for $fileCode in $root/file[identity/@fileType eq 'listOfFiles']/fileContent/fileEntry/fileCode 
return
    if (local:isValid($fileCode))
    then   <filePresent>1</filePresent>  
    else <fileNonPresent>2</fileNonPresent>

}
</result>
```

The code above is running for a small databse but for mine, it is requiring a incredible amount of time.

SO, I wonder if someone can help me to improve that code in order to execute it in a reasonable time ;)

(My database is indexed)

Thanks for your help !!

Johann

Comment: I can't edit my post :( Sorry for not saying "Hello"

Comment: Saying hello is not the custom. Can you tell which database you use? Utilizing indexes might require using proprietary extensions, or optimizing your expressions to match the built-in optimization. 30k docs is not much, but enough to want to use indexes.

Comment: I have to create a benchmark on several databases (baseX, marklogic, oracle db XML and qizx). For the moment I'm using BaseX.

Comment: Optimizing a query typically involves specifics of the given database so I'm not sure this is a particularly great question as asked.  That is, I would expect different answers for each database.  Not one answer for all databases you've listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the *Attribute Index* isn't applied to the attribute checks in the `local:isValid` function. You can achieve that by rewriting them as XPath predicates:

```
declare variable $root :=  fn:collection();

declare function local:isValid($fileCode) {
  $root/dmodule/identity/dmCode[@attribute1 = $fileCode/@attribute1
    and @attribute2 = $fileCode/@attribute2
    and @attribute3 = $fileCode/@attribute3]
};

<result> { 
  for $fileCode in $root/file[identity/@fileType = 'listOfFiles']/fileContent/fileEntry/fileCode 
  return
    if (local:isValid($fileCode))
      then   <filePresent>1</filePresent>  
      else <fileNonPresent>2</fileNonPresent>
}</result>
```

After these changes, the *Query Info* view in BaseX tells me that the index is used:

```
Compiling:
- pre-evaluating fn:collection()
- rewriting And expression to predicate(s)
- rewriting fn:boolean(@*:attribute1 = $fileCode/@attribute1)
- rewriting fn:boolean(@*:attribute2 = $fileCode/@attribute2)
- rewriting fn:boolean(@*:attribute3 = $fileCode/@attribute3)
- applying attribute index
- applying attribute index
```

and the evaluation time drops from 4'500ms to ~20ms for my test data.

Comment: There is something strange when I test your solution :
BaseX is unable to execute something... It runs, runs and runs again with "Please wait..." even for a small test.

Have I mistaken in the configuration ?

Comment: Do you have/can you create a sample collection of manageable size that we can test our suggestions with? It's much easier to get right that way.

Comment: In fact, I m just testing with only 5 XML files (28 Mo) and when I click on the "Run" button, it is written "Please Wait..." and nothing happens

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share my files, they are Airbus' data. 
But I guess it's not a problem of data : Why does it take such a long time to query just 5 files ?
With my previous code (on the first post) with the same 5 files, it only takes 3000 ms but with your change "Please Wait..." for 30 min now

Comment: Johan are you using the latest version of BaseX? Maybe you could also make sure the indices are all up to date running the `optimize all` command? I guess Leo’s query should be optimized for your data as well.

Comment: Well, it has to have something to do with the data, as my modifications made the query much faster on my test collection (http://www.mediafire.com/?mgzxnpqlgdkrgyt). Could you show us the part after `Compiling:` in the `Query Info` view in BaseX after you cancelled the query?

Comment: Did you try it another time? Did you try it from command line, too? In my experience, BaseX is very advanced when it comes to the optimization of nested and index-supported queries, so I believe that rewritings motivated by Leo should be successful.

Answer (score 3):

For MarkLogic you will need to be aware that index lookups happen only in certain expressions and functions. In this case you need more compact code. Here's a form that should produce the same results, but will use indexes in a simple way:

```
<result>
{
    for $fileCode in
      collection()/
      file[identity/@fileType eq "listOfFiles"]/
      fileContent/
      fileEntry/
      fileCode
    let $fc1 := $fileCode/@attribute1/string()
    let $fc2 := $fileCode/@attribute2/string()
    let $fc3 := $fileCode/@attribute3/string()
    return
      if (collection()/
          dmodule/
          identity/
          dmCode[
            @attribute1 eq $fc1][
            @attribute2 eq $fc2][
            @attribute3 eq $fc3])
      then <filePresent>1</filePresent>
      else <fileNonPresent>2</fileNonPresent>
  }
</result>
```

However that code will perform one database lookup per `listOfFiles` entry, which is not optimal.

It is possible to optimize further. First, MarkLogic is a document-oriented database in which every document has a unique URI. So it would be much more efficient if you simply encoded the three attribute values into each document URI. We might use something like `string-join(($fc1, $fc2, $fc3), '/')` to build the URIs. Then you could check for each value using a `doc()` call, which is more efficient than an XPath lookup - even when using indexes. And once that change is made, the `listOfFiles` document might as well store URIs rather than attribute values.

Second, I think the results format is not very useful. It tells you that some documents are missing, but not which ones. I would refactor so that the code only returns the missing document URIs. We might also enable an extra index available in MarkLogic: the URI lexicon.  This automatically maintains a value index of all document URIs, sort of like your `listOfFiles` document. Using the URI lexicon, I could write:

```
<result>{
    let $uris :=
      collection()/
      file[identity/@fileType eq "listOfFiles"]/
      fileContent/
      fileEntry/
      fileCode/
      string-join(
        (@attribute1/string(),
         @attribute2/string(),
         @attribute3/string()),
        "/")
    let $uris-present := cts:uris((), "document", cts:document-query($uris))
    for $uri in $uris
    where not($uri = $uris-present)
    return <missing>{ $uri }</missing>
}</result>
```

That requires only one database lookup, and does the rest of the necessary work in memory. It should scale much better than either your original query or my first iteration. If you do not agree with my reworking of the results format, and still want to see a result for every input `fileCode`, you can refactor the `...where...return...` clause into `...return...if...then...else...` as in your original query.

Be sure to use the profile tool in https://github.com/marklogic/cq - it can help you try out alternatives and spot opportunities for optimization.

Comment: Quick addendum re: profiling. A similar profile tool now ships with the product as part of Query Console (point browser to `http://yourserver:8000/qconsole`), so if you're running MarkLogic 5, you won't really need cq.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include eXist-db in your list of test systems, but in case you are interested in benchmarking it with your data, there's a great article on optimizing your queries and using indexes intelligently to speed up performance in eXist-db.  See http://exist-db.org/exist/tuning.xml.  Your query as you posted it should work fine without modification, but the advice in the article will definitely help you improve performance.  If you need help, feel free to post to the exist-open mailing list.

Regardless of which system you go with, I'd be very interested to know your results - and not only me - I think there would be broad interest.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic should process your query fast if you define an Attribute-Range index on each of the attributes you are using in the comparison.

You can do this via MarkLogic Admin UI (http://*hostname*:8001):

- Select your database under Databases
- Select Attribute Range Indexes on the left hand side
- Choose Add to define a new Attribute Range Index
- Specify the element (dmcode) and attribute (attribute1, attribute2, attribute3) referring to the range index (don't forget to specify the namespace if your element is in a certain namespace).
- Click OK to create the range index.

What version of MarkLogic are you using?
If you are using MarkLogic 5, you can also use Query Console to test your query:

(http://*hostname*:8000/qconsole)

Feel free to ask if you have any question/ let me know how it goes.
I'm from MarkLogic and happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

does it help to replace the “eq“ with an equal sign (=)?

Comment: It does not change anything in terms of performance... I have just tested

Comment: did you try different versions of basex (e.g. BaseX 7 vs 7.1)? in general, queries like yours should be optimized with the existing (automatically created) value indexes, so feel free to provide us with some anonymized XML snippets!